# Updating APK Issue in targetSdkVersion 28(Non Market)

Tags: android, updates, auto-update, target-sdk, targetsdkversion

APK is updating well till targetSdkVersion **24**, But it is having an issue in **28(latest)**. My app is not on PlayStore.if Version Number changes it needs to update. The issue is App is not updated when the version number is incremented in 28 targetSdkVersion
Here is my code:

```
try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + "/Download/"+appName);
        file.setReadable(true, false);
        Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(UpdateActivity.this, getPackageName()+ ".provider",
                    file);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE, fileUri);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
        intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android" + ".package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went Wrong.Remove old XYZ app & install it from Download folder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in Manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.updateapp.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Provider Path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

I need it to update APK in targetSdkVersion 28.Appreciate for help thank you

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: And your question is ... what, exactly? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: app is not able to update when version code is incremented.

Comment: is there any solution ?